# Loops, if statements, Function using inputFile outputs only 0's

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, inputstream, validation

**I need some serious help getting this to run. I think I am messing up the loops with the inputFile.. The program compiles and the .txt file is in the proper directory. The txt is a test file that replaces user input. The file contains three numbers on three separate lines: 1, 115, and 10.
Here is my code:**

```
//Headers
//Headers
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
using
namespace std;
void PaintJobEstimator(double gallonprice, double wallspace)
{
    double numBucket;
    double hours;
    double bucketCost;
    double laborCharges;
    double totalCost;
    {
    //calculates number of buckets of paint (gallons) needed
    numBucket=1/115*wallspace;
    //calculates paint cost
    bucketCost=gallonprice*numBucket;
    //calculates labor hour
    hours=8/115*wallspace;
    //calculates labor charges
    laborCharges=hours*18;
    //calculates total cost
    totalCost=bucketCost+laborCharges;
    //Console output
    {
        cout << "The number of Gallons of paint required:\t" << numBucket << endl;
        cout << "The hours of labor required:\t" << hours << " hrs" << endl;
        cout << "The labor charges:\t$" << laborCharges << endl;
        cout << "The cost of the paint:\t$" << bucketCost << endl;
        cout << "The total cost of the paint job:\t$" << totalCost << endl;
    }

    }

}

int main ()
{
    int rooms=0; //number of rooms
    double wallspace=0; //wall space measured in square meters
    double gallonprice=0; //Price per gallon
    cout << "=========================================================\n";
    cout << "___________________Paint Job Estimator___________________\n";
    cout << "_________________________________________________________\n";
    //by Jeff Youngblood
    cout << endl;
    ifstream inputFile;
    //open the file
    inputFile.open("17.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        if (rooms>=1) //validates rooms
        {
            inputFile >> rooms;
        }
        for (int roomNum=1;roomNum<=rooms;roomNum++)
        {
            if (wallspace>1)//validates and inputs wallspace
            {
                inputFile >> wallspace;
            }
        }
        //end loop
        while (gallonprice>10) //validates price per gallon
        {
            inputFile >> gallonprice;
        }
        PaintJobEstimator(gallonprice,wallspace);
        system ("pause");
    }
    else
        cout <<"Error reading file '17.txt', please check your directory.\n";
}
```

Comment: Last I checked, 1/115 and 8/115 were both 0...

Comment: try casting to double: double(1)/double(115) and double(8)/double(115)

Comment: @mcdg: in fact, just reording the multiplication to `wallspace*1/115` will work as the elevation to double happens for `wallspace*1` and then the division is a double division. `wallspace/115` would still be a better choice....

Comment: @PhilH I agree with you. Your solution is better!

Answer (score 2):

This sequence

```
    double wallspace = 0;
    //...
    if (wallspace>1) //validates and inputs wallspace
    {
        inputFile >> wallspace;
    }
```

doesn't work, as the condition in the if-statement is always false. When you get there, the `wallspace` has the value zero so you never try to input the new value.

Similar for `gallonprice`, you never input a value because the initial condition is false so the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 1):

All your file reads are conditional, expecting values greater than zero, but since you `init` rooms, wallspace, and gallonprice with zero, the file is never read. `PaintJobEstimator` is hence called with 0,0. Try removing the conditions and work your way from there.